# Installed Cygwin n downloaded MAV for Win .I opened the Cygwin n navigated to 1 of the vehicle dir. (Copter) and called sim_vehicle.py to start SITL

Tags: python

23 aditi@DESKTOP-9EEMTR0 ~/ardupilot/ArduCopter
$ ../Tools/autotest/sim_vehicle.py --map --console
SIM_VEHICLE: Start
SIM_VEHICLE: Killing tasks
SIM_VEHICLE: kill_tasks failed: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
SIM_VEHICLE: Starting up at -35.363261,149.165230,584,353 (CMAC)
SIM_VEHICLE: WAF build
SIM_VEHICLE: Configure waf
SIM_VEHICLE: "/home/aditi/ardupilot/modules/waf/waf-light" "configure" "--board" "sitl"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/aditi/ardupilot/modules/waf/waflib/Node.py", line 579, in ant_iter
raise StopIteration
StopIteration

```
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aditi/ardupilot/modules/waf/waflib/Scripting.py", line 165, in waf_entry_point
    run_commands()
  File "/home/aditi/ardupilot/modules/waf/waflib/Scripting.py", line 262, in run_commands
    parse_options()
  File "/home/aditi/ardupilot/modules/waf/waflib/Scripting.py", line 214, in parse_options
    Context.create_context('options').execute()
  File "/home/aditi/ardupilot/modules/waf/waflib/Options.py", line 271, in execute
    super(OptionsContext, self).execute()
  File "/home/aditi/ardupilot/modules/waf/waflib/Context.py", line 205, in execute
    self.recurse([os.path.dirname(g_module.root_path)])
  File "/home/aditi/ardupilot/modules/waf/waflib/Context.py", line 287, in recurse
    user_function(self)
  File "/home/aditi/ardupilot/wscript", line 49, in options
    opt.load('compiler_cxx compiler_c waf_unit_test python')
  File "/home/aditi/ardupilot/modules/waf/waflib/Context.py", line 197, in load
    fun(self)
  File "/home/aditi/ardupilot/modules/waf/waflib/Tools/compiler_cxx.py", line 103, in options
    opt.load_special_tools('cxx_*.py')
  File "/home/aditi/ardupilot/modules/waf/waflib/Context.py", line 609, in load_special_tools
    lst = self.root.find_node(waf_dir).find_node('waflib/extras').ant_glob(var)
  File "/home/aditi/ardupilot/modules/waf/waflib/Node.py", line 672, in ant_glob
    ret = [x for x in self.ant_iter(accept=accept, pats=[to_pat(incl), to_pat(excl)], maxdepth=kw.get('maxdepth', 25), dir=dir, src=src, remove=kw.get('remove', True))]
  File "/home/aditi/ardupilot/modules/waf/waflib/Node.py", line 672, in <listcomp>
    ret = [x for x in self.ant_iter(accept=accept, pats=[to_pat(incl), to_pat(excl)], maxdepth=kw.get('maxdepth', 25), dir=dir, src=src, remove=kw.get('remove', True))]
RuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration
SIM_VEHICLE: (Configure waf) exited with code 512
SIM_VEHICLE: Killing tasks
SIM_VEHICLE: kill_tasks failed: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what exactly it is, but you may have just made a mistake somewhere in your Python file based on << a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' >> meaning somewhere you should not enter a string, But you entered a string and you should not do this

Maybe in file sim_vehicle.py